# Get rid of black border around mapbox-gl-js based maps when map is clicked

Tags: css, mapbox-gl-js

Using Chrome when you click a mapbox gl js based map e.g. on this page:
https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/
a black border of about 1 px is shown.
How can I remove that border?
I tried with setting `style="outline: none !important;"` or `style="outline: 0px transparent !important;"` without success. Any ideas?

Comment: add `outline: none!important` to `iframe canvas { }`.  Outline is appearing on canvas, not on iframe (assuming you are trying to style the iframe).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `outline: none` on the `<canvas>` element fixed it for me.

Comment: Awesome, just tried this here: https://jsfiddle.net/thiswiederkehr/mbqx4s7L/6/ it indeed works.